# Error: socket hang up code: 'ECONNRESET' on Google cloud storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

We keep getting ECONNRESET error when trying to upload images to google cloud storage.

```
var storage = require('gcloud').storage({
    projectId: projectNumber,
    credentials: credentials
});

//...

var file = Storage.bucket('myBucket').file('test.png');
fs.createReadStream('/path/to/image.png').pipe(file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
        contentType: 'image/png',
        cacheControl: 'public, max-age=2592000'
    }
}).on('complete', function () {
  //
}).on('error', function (err) {
  // err = Error: socket hang up || Request Timeout after 30000ms
});
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998079/socket-hang-up-econnreset-error-while-uploading-to-google-cloud-storage

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why no one has answered this question.
I have the same error, and resolve it by setting **resumable** and **validation** to **false**:

```
var gcsStream = Storage.bucket('myBucket').file('test.png').createWriteStream({
      resumable: false,
      validation: false,
      metadata: {
        contentType: 'image/png'
      }
    });
fs.createReadStream('/path/to/image.png').pipe(gcsStream);
```

Without the 2 settings, I get Socket hangup error whenever I upload 20~30 images at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still relevant but I was facing the same issue. However for me what ended up causing the error was these two things:

```js
const [exists] = await file.exists();
```

And

```js
const writeStream = file.createWriteStream();
fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
        res.body.pipe(writeStream);
        res.body.on('error', err => {
            reject(err);
        });
        writeStream.on('finish', async () => {
            resolve();
        });
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

It is important to note that there is (in my case) nothing wrong with these things but the problem lied with the amount of requests we where doing over a short amount of time. We where pushing 200 to 600 new images to google at once.

What worked for us was so simply add a `setTimeout()` with something like `40 * index` as timer. This worked for us as this was an action that didn't need to be fast or something. It just had to work.